# How to manually marshal a .NET object as a dual COM interface?

Tags: c#, .net, com, idispatch

I have written some C# code which returns a .NET object to unmanaged code as an `IDispatch` pointer using `Marshal.GetIDispatchForObject`, however, this object also implements other (non .NET defined) COM interfaces.
In the unmanaged world `QueryInterface` for these interfaces works fine, however, calling methods on them never breaks into my .NET code and seems to return default values only (0).

Is it possible to Marshal a .NET object as a dual interface, such that it may be used through `IDispatch` or by querying for particular interfaces? My type is public, `ComVisible` and I tried applying `[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]` without luck.

I've had no problems getting things to work using `UnmanagedType.Interface` marshaling, however, supporting `IDispatch` as well seems problematic. If there is an *easy* way to "manually" implement `IDispatch` this would also be an acceptable solution.

Comment: It's been a long time since I've been in these weeds, but I think you should set the class interface attribute to `None` and manually implement the [`IReflect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.ireflect(v=vs.110).aspx) interface yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ICustomQueryInterface interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.icustomqueryinterface.aspx). It will allow you to return IUnknown interfaces "manually" and still benefit from the IDispatch implementation provided by .NET.
So, for example, if you have an unmanaged IUnknown interface "IMyUnknown" that contains one method (named "MyUnknownMethod" in the sample), you can declare your .NET class like this:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public class Class1 : ICustomQueryInterface, IMyUnknown
{
    CustomQueryInterfaceResult ICustomQueryInterface.GetInterface(ref Guid iid, out IntPtr ppv)
    {
        if (iid == typeof(IMyUnknown).GUID)
        {
            ppv = Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject(this, typeof(IMyUnknown), CustomQueryInterfaceMode.Ignore);
            return CustomQueryInterfaceResult.Handled;
        }

        ppv = IntPtr.Zero;
        return CustomQueryInterfaceResult.NotHandled;
    }

    // an automatic IDispatch method
    public void MyDispatchMethod()
    {
       ...
    }

    // the IMyUnknown method
    // note you can declare that method with a private implementation
    public void MyUnknownMethod()
    {
       ...
    }
}
```